# How to set loader after form validation using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

**Form code**

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="@GlobalVariable.URL/api/fileupload/Profile" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
```

...(some code)

```
<button type="submit" id="Test" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
```

and my loader code is

```
<div id="divLoading" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: fixed; right: 0px;
    top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: #666666; z-index: 30001;
    opacity: .8; filter: alpha(opacity=70);display:none">
    <p style="position: absolute; top: 30%; left: 45%; color: White;">
        <img src='@Url.Content(" ~/Content/ajax-loader.gif ")' />
    </p>
</div>
```

How to make the loader active after form validation ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code should work,

```
$(".form-horizontal").validate({
    rules: {
        field: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $('#divLoading').show();
        form.submit();
   }
});
```

http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate

Comment: I have used jquery validation plugin for the form so will it work ?

Comment: check the documentation in the link and try it yourself. it should work